# How to turn a comma-delimited list of date attributes into a MySQL date value?

Tags: python, mysql, shell

Not sure if I've worded my title correctly but here goes. I have a file of jobs which are all in a similar format to this:

```
423720,hparviz,RUN,512,22,Mar,10:38,11,April,14:06
```

Basically from this I need to covert the start date and end date to a format which allows me to import it into mysql (22-Mar 10:38 - 11-Apr 14:06 or however MySQL requires dates to be formatted). This data is extracted using a command in linux, in which I'm manipulating the results to allow importation to a MySQL database. Would it be easier to manipulate in Linux (during the command), in Python (in the state I've shown) or MySQL (after importation).

If you need any more details let me know, thanks.

Comment: This is incredibly easy in Python. Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: Because I have about 50 other lines in similar format, how do I go about selecting the date, month and time using a loop?

Comment: You might want to look at [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming every line looks like what you posted:

```
f=open(filename,"r")
listOfLines=f.readlines()
for line in listOfLines:
    splitLine=line.split(",")
    print "Day of Month: "+splitLine[4]#this is an example of one piece of info.
    print "Month: "+splitLine[5]#this is an example of one piece of info.
```

Comment: Consider not using `readlines`, but iterating over the file-like directly.

Answer (score 3):

you can split the line with `string.split(',')`.
You can than convert the date using [time.strftime](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime)

Answer (score 2):

```
process to create data | awk -F, -v OFS=, '
  function format_date(day, mon, time) {
    return sprintf("%s-%s %s", day, substr(mon,1,3), time)
  }
  {print $1,$2,$3,$4,format_date($5,$6,$7),format_date($8,$9,$10)}
'
```

Outputs

```
423720,hparviz,RUN,512,22-Mar 10:38,11-Apr 14:06
```

Alter the format string as required.